# wordpress : Adding a dynamic post filter menu

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, posts

I have started building a simple wordpress theme for my online portfolio. You can see it here.

http://www.cool-penguin.co.uk/wordpress/?page_id=2

I was wondering the best way to add a sub menu above my post thumbnails that will dynamically filter the post category's. I have seen this done in many portfolio Wordpress themes and would be interested to know how it is done and what the easiest way to implement it into my theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Desandro isotope
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ 
here as ready to use wp plugin
https://mintthemes.com/isotope-for-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks Michal. I have looked at using isotope and their seems many different variations of it. I have installed the ready to use version but I cannot get it to work.When I add it everything on the page disappears like it is now. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: In console you can see a js error, line 322 - please check it.

Comment: Sorry for the pate response. I have had a look at the errors and cannot work out the issue. The only thing I can think of is that my theme does not use <div <?php post_class(); ?> > in it and this is causing errors.

Comment: Just wrap your post code with <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>> ... </div> if class is not in css will just and line end (after div)

Comment: Thanks Michal for the help so far. I have added <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>> around the loop on the index.php as I want it to appear on my post page but still not appearing. The strange thing is I added it to my category page and it appears here as a drop down menu but with no options. Could you let us know if I have added the  post_class and  the isotope shortcode in the correct place please.

Comment: yes it's in right place, but you have to remove <ol><ul><li></li></ul></ol> tree. Isotope moves post div's (changes absolute position of post dive in relation to .moveplugins_isotopes_container

Comment: I have removes the <ol><ul><li></li></ul></ol> tree but its messed up my layout. I left it like this for the moment for you to see. Im probaly missing the obvious but it confused how to fix this and also the filter menu will not appear.

Comment: good direction to clean it up :) now you miss one </div> after post.

Comment: Thank for that. I think I have cleaned it up now and layout has gone back to how it was which is good. Only problem is I still have no filter navigation menu. Any ideas?

Comment: Almost done :) add a links like <ul data-option-key="filter" class="isotopenav"><li><a href="#filter" valuemint="*">All</a></li><li><a href="#filter" valuemint=".tag-band">Band</a></li> use tags applied to your posts (shuld be visible in source code as post class like tag-band) (one more thing <a></a> links must be in class="isotopenav")

Comment: and scripts for some reason are in wrong order, first you have isotope, then jquery - have to be opposite.

Comment: Its working!! Thank you so much, I was beginning to lose hope. The navigation is now working really nice. No worries if not but would there be an easy way to to make it filter by Categories instead of tags. If its complicated then no worries.

Comment: in fact i also prefer categories, you have add code to add class called after category name and then use it as a filter. Difficult may be because of fact one post can have many cat. So you have to add a loop to add them. Look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Comment: if answer was useful, vote up will be appreciated :)

Comment: I would give you a vote up but I do not have enough reputation. I will add a vote up as soon as my rep increases above 15.